# Return a Point without Dim as Point

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to understand how I can write the following code without writing `Dim StartingPoint` / or create a Point throught a dim. **The following code moves the cursor to the offset value of User Control**

```
Private Sub MoveToStart()
    Dim StartingPoint = Panel1.Location()           ' Get User Control Location
    StartingPoint.Offset(10, 10)                    ' Set Cursor Point offset
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(StartingPoint)  ' Move the Cursor to position
End Sub
```

I would love to write it along the lines of:

```
Private Sub MoveToStart()
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(Panel1.Location.Offset(10, 10))
End Sub
```

The following code: `Cursor.Position = PointToScreen()` needs me to return a Point . But I really can't figure out how to do it without a dim.

Comment: `Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)` if that's what you mean? But why on earth do you want to do this without a `Dim`? In fact it makes for easier reading if you use it...

Comment: Make a Function returning a Point?

Comment: Why the need for it? Less lines? The Dim doesn't create a new point in your example.

Comment: Thank you both! I was looking for the alternative way of doing it without a dim, hoping for less code, which would result in easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Offset() is a subroutine which does not return a value, but instead changes the values of the target

If you really need it in one line, you can do so without calling offset like this:

```
Private Sub MoveToStart()
    Cursor.Position = New Point(PointToScreen(Panel1.Location()).X + 10, PointToScreen(Panel1.Location()).Y + 10)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Reddit I got another answer [Reset Cursor Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/visualbasic/comments/6yf5sh/vbnet_reset_cursor_position/?st=j7bex51a&sh=f791e3ce).

```
Private Sub MoveToStart()
  Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(Panel1.Location)
  Cursor.Position.Offset(10,10)
End Sub
```